# Writing (and reading) bits to binary files in Perl + EOF handling

Tags: perl, binary, bit-manipulation

I have two related problems (in Perl):

1. Write data to binary files, in the format: single bit flag followed by 8 bits
2. Read back the same format

I tried this (and other variations but for the life of me I can't figure this out):

```
binmode(OUT);
my $bit = pack("B1", '1');
my $byte = pack("H2", "02");
print OUT $bit . $byte;
```

Using a hex editor, I see I get 16 bits:

```
1000000000000020
```

What I want is 9 bits:

```
100000020
```

Also: Suppose I write out two of these patterns. That means I end up with 9 + 9 = 18 bits. I am not sure how to handle the last byte (padding?)

This is to compress and uncompress files, with space at premium. I was hoping there would be some simple idiomatic way to do this that I am not aware of.

Comment: File data that isn't built out of whole multiples of bytes is very tricky to code for and slow at run time. Are you sure you need to do this? It would probably help if you explained a bit of background to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bit::Vector to manage your bits and conversion with some more ease,

```
use Bit::Vector;

my $bit = Bit::Vector->new_Bin( 1, '1' );

my $byte     = Bit::Vector->new_Bin( 8, '00000010' );
my $byte_9   = Bit::Vector->new_Bin( 9, '000000010' );
my $nineBits = Bit::Vector->new_Bin( 9, '100000000' );
my $carry    = Bit::Vector->new_Bin( 9, '000000000' );
my $ORed     = Bit::Vector->new_Bin( 9, '000000000' );
my $added    = Bit::Vector->new_Bin( 9, '000000000' );


$ORed->Union($nineBits,$byte_9);

print "bit: 0x". $bit->to_Hex(). "\n";
print "byte 2: 0x". $byte->to_Hex(). "\n";
print "nineBits: 0x". $nineBits->to_Hex(). "\n";
print "nineBits: 0x". $nineBits->to_Bin(). "\n";
print "ORed bit and byte 0x". $ORed->to_Dec(). "\n";

open BINOUT, ">out.bin"
    or die "\nCan't open out.bin for writing: $!\n";

binmode BINOUT;

print BINOUT pack ('B*', $ORed->to_Bin()) ."\n"
```

Here's the output

```
>perl bitstuff.pl
bit: 0x1
byte 2: 0x02
nineBits: 0x100
nineBits: 0x100000000
ORed bit and byte 0x-254
>cat out.bin 
\201^@
```

Comment: Thanks michaelt. this seems what I was looking for. Going to try now

Comment: You may want to google how to install the perl module, if you've never done it before.  I installed it from the cpan shell using the commandline **sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell** then typing **install Bit::Vector**.

Comment: I ended up using this approach and it did solve my problem. I still need to review and understand ikegami's answer

Comment: ikegami's way is intrinsic to perl and requires no external libs, though notably it does require a better understanding of perl.  It also stands to reason his way may be faster as well, probably worth checking out for at least that reason.

Answer (score 5):

Files are sequences of bytes. If you want to print out bits, you'll have to use some form of buffering.

```
my $bits = '';
$bits .= '1';                                        # Add 1 bit.
$bits .= unpack('B8', pack('C', 0x02));              # Add 8 bits.
$bits .= substr(unpack('B8', pack('C', 0x02)), -6);  # Add 6 bits.
```

This prints as much as the buffer as possible:

```
my $len = ( length($bits) >> 3 ) << 3;
print($fh, pack('B*', substr($bits, 0, $len, '')));
```

You'll eventually need to pad the buffer so that you have a multiple of 8 bits in order to flush out the rest. You could simply pad with zeroes.

```
$bits .= "0" x ( -length($bits) % 8 );
```

If you're smart, though, you can come up with a padding scheme that can be used to indicate where the file actually ends. Remember, you can't rely on just the file length anymore. If you don't use a smart padding scheme, you'll have to use another method.

One example of a smart padding scheme would be:

```
$bits .= "0";
$bits .= "1" x ( -length($bits) % 8 );
```

Then, to unpad, remove all trailing `1` bits and the `0` bit before that.

Comment: ikegami, this is a bit harder for me to follow, but I will delve into this as well

Comment: It doesn't require you holding the entire string in memory. It also mentions two very important issues the other answer doesn't: You need to pad somehow (he just assumed you wanted to zero pad to 8 bits), and you have no intrinsic way of knowing the actual file length anymore. It also shows how to solve both problems at once.